# What internal tables are automatically created by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm working on blacklisting these for the [data analysis tool Metabase](http://www.metabase.com/).

I can't find any lists anywhere that specify which tables the framework creates, but I want to make sure I get db migration / ActiveRecord ones and other internal ones created by the framework that a user likely wouldn't be interested in looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only table that Rails (or rather ActiveRecord) creates regardless of application models is `schema_migrations`.

Comment: I believe there are more than this. Additionally, there's the `sessions` table and as of Rails 5, there's a table for `ar_internal_metadata` if I'm not mistaken. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/07/rails-5-prevents-destructive-action-on-production-db.html

Answer (score 1):

By default rails does not create any table when you create a new app.
But when you add a migration for create table that time rails create a table schema_migrations and that is used to save version of the migrations.
This table will create with first table when run `rake db:migrate`